# Remix - Low level call within a smart contract not executed properly

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

I am trying to perform low-level calls (function "Safe_swapV3") within my smart contract. The goal is to perform a transaction even if the sub-function "SwapV3" is reverted.
I am testing on Goerli and getting results like this: transaction goes to the blockchain but NO transfer of funds occurs - looking in depth into the transaction, the first internal call results failed - so I believe the problem is the invocation of the Call function. When debugging on Remix I get an empty string as call data result.

[image]

Can you please help me debugging the code?
Thanks!!

```
    function SwapV3 (uint Quantity_in, uint Min_quantity, address Address_quote, address Address_token_out, address Recipient) public payable{
        require ((msg.sender==owner) || (msg.sender==address(this)), "Only owner can swap tokens");
        uint256 deadline = block.timestamp;
        address tokenIn = Address_quote;
        address tokenOut = Address_token_out;
        uint24 fee = 3000;
        address recipient = Recipient;
        uint256 amountIn = Quantity_in;
        uint256 amountOutMinimum = Min_quantity;
        uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0;
        V3.ExactInputSingleParams memory Parameters = V3.ExactInputSingleParams(tokenIn,tokenOut,fee,recipient,deadline,amountIn,amountOutMinimum,sqrtPriceLimitX96);
        V3(Swapper).exactInputSingle(Parameters); 
    } 

    function Safe_swapV3 (uint Quantity_in, uint Min_quantity, address Address_quote, address Address_token_out, address Recipient) public payable {
        require (msg.sender==owner, "Only owner can swap tokens");
        (bool success, bytes memory result)=address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("SwapV3 (uint,uint,address,address,address)",Quantity_in, Min_quantity, Address_quote, Address_token_out, Recipient));
    }
```

Comment: can you send the link to the transaction the thing is when you use call and the gas is not enough the transaction will revert

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4010d87503727a820314d9ae5ee976c4c27c71fe123892ec701b6c47e2010426

Comment: increase the gas

Comment: already tried, doesn't work - https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xab7ec05c4fab08b70d7193b1a5eb96570c74398ac9fc4d03ca415ef88e033bcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function call signature is wrong

```
"SwapV3(uint256,uint256,address,address,address)"
```

No white spaces, uint -> uint256. Also check the function name case.